# How to read the input(line by line) from a multiline Tkinter Textbox in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

By Using Procedural Programming Paradigm in Python, I have a written a program which reads the input of a file(say File.txt) line by line and print it. Below is the Example:

**Script:**

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(r'D:\File.txt'):
    line = line.replace(" ", "")
    line = line[0:-1]
    print(line)
```

**Result:**

Note: If for example "File.txt" contains 2 lines, First line as 'line1' and Second line as 'line2', then output is:

```
line1
line2
```

Same Result I want through Object Oriented programing Paradigm by using "Tkinter Multiline TextBox" instead of a file(here in above example File.txt).

I have the Below Code that creates a MultiLine Tkinter TextBox:

```
import tkinter as tki # Tkinter -> tkinter in Python3
class App(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tki.Tk()

    # create a Frame for the Text and Scrollbar
        txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=200, height=200)
        txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # ensure a consistent GUI size
        txt_frm.grid_propagate(False)

        # implement stretchability
        txt_frm.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        txt_frm.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # create a Text widget
        self.txt = tki.Text(txt_frm, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken")
        self.txt.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.txt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

    # create a Scrollbar and associate it with txt
        scrollb = tki.Scrollbar(txt_frm, command=self.txt.yview)
        scrollb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.txt['yscrollcommand'] = scrollb.set

    def retrieve_input():
        input = self.txt.get("0.0",END)
        print(input)
app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
app.retrieve_input()
```

Now My Problem is, once I run the above code a "Tkinter Multiline TextBox" is coming and I am entering 4 Lines in the Tkinter TextBox as:

```
ABC
XYZ
PQR
QAZ
```

But I am not getting the Exact Idea/Implementation that How I can read those lines form Tkinter TextBox one by one and Use them for further processing in My Program.

Python Version I am using is 3.0.1.
Please Help...

Answer (score 3):

From the document, the `get` method on `tkinter.text` will just return the string, including the new line `\n`. You can not treat the `tkinter.text` as file, but you can use other ways.

1. Read them all and split them into a list. Loop the list then.

   ```
   def retrieve_input():
       text = self.txt.get('1.0', END).splitlines()
       for line in text:
           ...
   ```
2. Using `io.StringIO` to emulate a file, but in this case it will not strip the newline.

   ```
   def retrieve_input():
       text = io.StringIO(self.txt.get('1.0', END))
       for line in text:
           line = line.rstrip()
           ...
   ```

Comment: Text.get('0.0') return only the first character.

Comment: Are you sure? The doc tells me if the second argument is omitted it will return characters after the first argument. I will have a try to see.@falsetru

Comment: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html. You may have a look. This is a source from the official documentation.@falsetru

Comment: According to the document you give: Retrieval starts at index index1. If the second argument is omitted, you get the **character** after index1. (not characters)

Comment: Another issue: Text widget's line numbers start at 1, while column numbers start at 0.

Comment: @falsetru and zhangyangyu: Your Answer and Comments both Are helpful for me, I read the Links also. It helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I modifed your code.

- Added a button that will call `retrieve_input` on click.
- retrieve_input should have `self` parameter.

You can get text using `self.txt.get("1.0", tki.END)`. Use `str.splitlines()` to get lines as list.

```
import tkinter as tki

class App(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tki.Tk()

    # create a Frame for the Text and Scrollbar
        txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=200, height=200)
        txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # ensure a consistent GUI size
        txt_frm.grid_propagate(False)

        # implement stretchability
        txt_frm.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        txt_frm.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # create a Text widget
        self.txt = tki.Text(txt_frm, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken")
        self.txt.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.txt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

    # create a Scrollbar and associate it with txt
        scrollb = tki.Scrollbar(txt_frm, command=self.txt.yview)
        scrollb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.txt['yscrollcommand'] = scrollb.set

        tki.Button(txt_frm, text='Retrieve input', command=self.retrieve_input).grid(row=1, column=0)

    def retrieve_input(self):
        lines = self.txt.get("1.0", tki.END).splitlines()
        print(lines)

app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snip.  It helped me to get an IDEA for my Problem. I will ask you more If I will be trapped in Between my Problem for which I am working. Thanks